# Dynamic update to .li text

Tags: javascript, list, dynamic

I am needing a .li to update its text in response to the user's selections. There are three toggle switches (which currently adjust the .li with no problems), two sets of radio buttons, and an HTML5 slider. The two sets of radio buttons and slider work great together and display the resulting value in a div.

What I now need is for the value that is displayed in the div to be added to the value in the .li and adjusted whenever the user changes a radio selection or moves the slider (just like it does in the value displayed in the div).

I have this .li:

```
<li id="pricing" class="price"><i>$</i><span>850</span></li>
```

This code makes the switches change the text in .li according to the position of each switch:

```
(function($){
$(function(){
$('.cmn-toggle').each(function () {
$(this).change(function() {
var curr_class = '.' + $(this).attr('id');
var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
var price_box = $('.pricing-table li.price span');
$(curr_class).toggleClass('active');
if (price) {
  if ($(curr_class).hasClass('active')) {
    price_box.html(parseInt(price_box.html()) + parseInt(price));
  }
  else {
    price_box.html(parseInt(price_box.html()) - parseInt(price));
  }
}
});
});
});
})(jQuery);
```

This code takes the value of the user selections from each set of radios and the slider and displays it in the div:

```
function calculateTotal(){
var multi = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
var arr = document.getElementsByName('selectMedia');
var arry = document.getElementsByName('selectLength');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].checked){
        tot += Number(arr[i].value);
    }
}
for(var i=0; i<arry.length; i++){
    if(arry[i].checked){
        tot += Number(arry[i].value);
    }
}   
document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = tot * Number(multi);
}
```

What do I need now to dynamically update the .li based on the value in totalPrice? If .li is 850 and totalPrice is changed to 37 then .li needs to display 887. If totalPrice is changed to 100 then the .li needs to read 950.

[A jsfiddle with the rest of the code used.](http://jsfiddle.net/t2rn5hvk/)

Comment: Did you look at your fiddle? does it do what you want it to do? I only see a big mess of code and markup. Please create a MCVE (Read [ask])

Comment: Fiddle is repaired and working correctly. The slider and two sets of radio buttons correctly display their totals. The three check boxes correctly add/subtract their value depending upon user selection.

Now, how do I add/subtract the text displayed in totalPrice each time a users makes a different selection?